# How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address using as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address in as3? Anyone done this before. I googled it lot but i didn't get the solution for this. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to use an .ANE file made in java...

Comment: I tried for ANE but it is available for getting phone number not for e-mail